# Laravel : form does not change the URL after submit, causing me to be unable to do another POST in web.php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a bit of a complicated issue. I could use some help.

I have a form that is being handled by the following function:

```
$module = request('module');
        $classe = request('classe');
        $horaire = request('horaire');
        $date = request('date');
        $students = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `etudiants` WHERE etudiants.id_classe = '.$classe);
        return view('g_absence.absence',['module'=> $module, 'classe'=>$classe,'horaire'=>$horaire,'date'=>$date,'students'=>$students]);
```

I take the values $module, $class, $horaire, $date and $students and need to use them inside a different view: g_absence.absence. This works fine and when the view is returned I have access to said variables.

The issue is, inside the g_absence.absence view, I have another form that also needs to be handled, and because the url remains the same even tho a different view is returned, I cant make two posts for the same path.

web.php:

```
    Route::get('/testboy', [App\Http\Controllers\g_absence::class,'index'])->name('marquer');
    Route::post('/testboy',[App\Http\Controllers\g_absence::class, 'marquer']);
    Route::post('/testboy',[App\Http\Controllers\g_absence::class, 'ajoutabsence']);
```

- The first line is the one that send to the form page just a simple
  return view
- The second one handle the form in that view
- The third one, I want it to handle the form inside the
  g_absence.absence view, but they share the same path.

Excuse me if I'm being unclear, I'm a bit of a beginner in Laravel

Comment: This logic is incorrect. You cannot have the same resource (same method & same name/path) pointing to different endpoints.

Comment: you should rename your third route to something else and use that post route in the form in your g_absence.absence view, otherwise you will allways hit second route.

Comment: @Rubens When the form is open , the link that is opened is '/testboy', is it possible to renme the third route to something else even though the form will be used in '/testboy' ?

Comment: and @OP, you're not putting laravel to use in your code, never trust inputs coming from the users, so you need to use validations, and never use queries like that, put the eloquent ORM to use, what you did there is a recipe for disaster (SQL Injection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is using the same route for different methods
basically the first route gets executed every time you use the **'/testboy'** action that is why your second function never get's called.

you can solve this issue by changing your urls for example:

```
Route::post('/testboy-marquer',[App\Http\Controllers\g_absence::class, 'marquer']);
Route::post('/testboy-ajoutabsence',[App\Http\Controllers\g_absence::class, 'ajoutabsence']);
```

Or you can use one function that's handle both with one url by pathing additional parameter to your url depending on your function call :

```
Route::post('/testboy?type=marquer',[App\Http\Controllers\g_absence::class, 'ajoutabsence']);
```

in your function check the type :

```
if(request('type') == 'marquer') {
 execute marquer logic here...
} else {
 execute absence logic here...
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! There is another one in case he wanna leave the routes as he defined `/testbody` BY adding the name for them like adding `testbody.marquer` in the first route and `testbody.ajoutabsence` in the second one, then calling these routes by their names using `route` method like so `{{ route('testbody.ajoutabsence') }}`.

Comment: That is a very nice solution , I will try it out right now

Answer (score 0):

Using method and path with two functionalities is wrong, but if you want to somehow use both routes my same method and path which I don't recommend you must  let the request to pass through like a middleware in your first block of code Instead of return a view.

Recommended way is to have 2 routes with different paths or at least one route with a parameter by which you can determine what code block must be executed.